# Função para retornar o próprio nome do código fonte em python

Tags: python

Existe alguma função para retornar o próprio nome do arquivo fonte?

A intenção seria criar um arquivo de log, a qual um dos dados teria o nome do fonte que está gerando aquele log. Caso tenha erro, é mais fácil ir diretamente no arquivo fonte para poder dar manutenção.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

É só usar **`__file__`**.

Por exemplo:

```
print(__file__)
```

Também é possível importar o módulo `sys` e obter através dele o primeiro argumento da execução, que é sempre o nome do arquivo.

Por exemplo:

```
import sys
print(sys.argv[0])
```

Você pode usar `os.path.basename` para obter apenas o nome relativo do diretório. Isso evita que você precise usar um `split` e validar qual o lado da barra (já que no Windows a barra é do lado contrário dos sistemas *nix).

```
import os
print(os.path.basename(__file__))
```

Comment: Nesse caso, ele está pegando o caminho absoluto mais o nome do arquivo. Voce saberia de outra função para retornar somente o nome do arquivo? Obrigado!

Comment: @RodrigoSaito qual caso? Eu pus duas formas

Comment: Nos dois casos, ambos mostram o caminho absoluto mais o nome do arquivo

Comment: Python 2 ou 3? No meu acho que estava mostrando só o nome final mesmo. Agora não estou na frente do PC, então não tenho como testar. De qualquer forma você sempre pode dar um split por / e pegar a última posição do resultado.

Comment: Seria no python 3.
Boa idéia. Vou fazer uma função para receber a função, dar o split, verifcar o tamanho do vetor e retornar a última posição. Muito obrigado.

Comment: @RodrigoSaito Dei uma sugestão melhor ainda na resposta. Btw, você sempre pode marcar uma resposta como correta nas suas perguntas. É só usar o **V** do lado esquerdo  da resposta.

Comment: de forma alguma estou desmerecendo as suas resposta e agradeço por isso. Eu vou na verdade complementar a sua sugestão, pois vai ser usado diversas vezes, a qual encapsular tudo isso em uma função é melhor para não ficar repetindo código. Obrigado

Comment: @RodrigoSaito Claro, eu sei que não esta a desmerecer. Só deixei a dica pra complementar a resposta mesmo.